# axios.get() is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to fetch record with get API. That was working earlier but somehow it stopped working so after searching on this along with official document here is my code but that isn't working. It doesn't resolve promise

```
export const getDashboardService = (params, callback, errorCallback) => {
const url = baseUrl + getDashboard + userId;
console.log(url);
axios.get(
    url,
    {
        headers: {
            ...ServerConstants.serviceHeaderParameters,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${params.token}`
        }
    }
).then(function (response) {
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(response);
    if (callback != null) {
        callback(response);
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('elsefs');
    if (errorCallback != null) {
        errorCallback(error);
    }
}).finally(function () {
    console.log('in alwasy')
});
};
```

I am calling this function from another file here code for that

```
const getDashboard = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const requestParams = {
        userId: authReducer.userId,
        token: authReducer.userToken,
        limit: 20
    }
    await DashBoardServices.getDashboardService(
        requestParams,
        (response) => {
            setFetchedUsers(response.data.data.data);
        },
        (error) => {
            setErrorMessage(error.message);
        }
    );
    setIsLoading(false);
}
```

Here is version for react
"axios": "^0.21.4",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?